# how to capture the start and end of a trend from a group of elements in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Different start trend]

I need to capture the index of starting and ending position of blue trend and red trend separately; there are more than one such trend in the datapoint:

**Here's the sample data**

```
    freq
0    2.0
1    5.1
2    7.0
3   15.0
4   20.3
5   25.0
6   29.0
7   24.0
8    4.0
9    7.0
10   4.9
11   5.0
12  22.0
13   4.0
14  22.0
15   4.9
```

**so far I have tried this:**

```
z = []
y = []
for i in range(0,15):
    if tab['freq'][i] >= 5:
        i = i + 1   
        if tab['freq'][i] >= 5:
            if tab['freq'][i] >= 20:
                z.append(i)
                continue

            else:
                continue
        else:
            y.append(i)
    else:
        continue
print z
```

**output:**
   `[4, 5, 6, 7, 12] [8, 10, 13, 15]`

**expected output**

```
[4,12,14] [10]
```

**ideal output**

```
[[1,4],[11,12],[13,14]] [[8,10]] #indicating starting as well as ending point
```

In my code, I tried to capture the end point of the trend, but my code doesn't restrict to end point and captures every point after the limit value. I even tried using break after appending the index but it doesn't capture more than one instance.

Comment: Can you explain how you get that output?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ my output is different from the expected one. The append statement of z, y gives the output that I have got.

Comment: Can you explain the expected one then? Thanks.

Comment: Here the condition is to find when trend starts ; as in crossing the *Lower-limit*(5) and ending while crossing the *Upper-limit*(20)..making it a regular trend. If the trend starts (crossing the lower limit) but fails to cross the upper limit and instead crosses the lower limit..it reflect as aborted trend.

Comment: Your output is not homogeneous, the couples [13,14] and [8,10] do not respect the conditions you want as 13 and 8 are not upper or equal to your lower limit. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47032917/3941704 for a possible solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job iterating over the rows of a Pandas DataFrame.
`ll` and `ul` are respectively lower and upper limits.
You have to decide whether you consider starting/ending when `>=` or `>` that was not clear enough in your question.

```
tab = pd.DataFrame(dict(freq=[2.0,5.1,7.0,15.0,20.3,25.0,29.0,24.0,
                              4.0,7.0,4.9,5.0,22.0,4.0,22.0,4.9]))

ll = 5.0
ul = 20.0

z = [] #normal interruptions
z_ab = [] #abnormal interruption

#initialize start and endpoints to incoherent index
start = -1
end = -1

#loop over tab
for i, row in tab.iterrows():
    #get the starting index
    if (start==-1) & (end==-1) & (row.freq >= ll):
        start = i

    #get the ending index
    if (start != -1) & (end == -1):
        if row.freq >= ul:
            end = i
            z.append([start,end])
            start = -1
        if row.freq < ll:
            end = i
            z_ab.append([start,end])
            start = -1

    #say 'ok you can find a new cycle!'
    if (start==-1) & (end!=-1) & (row.freq<ll):
        end = -1
```

Result in :

```
z = [[1, 4], [11, 12], [14, 14]]
z_ab = [[9, 10]]
```

This is a solution, optimal solutions can be found I think.

Hope it helps though.